# How to loop through datagridview rows to delete entries if they have a record in the second column of 01 to 15?

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

[image: screenshot here]

Please check the screenshot provided above.

Basically what I want to achieve is to empty the rows from IN to DONE_ if they have a record of 01 to 15 in the DAY column.

Please enlighten me as I find it hard in dealing with loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want them to be replaced by nothing if second column < 16 so you do:

```
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
        If CInt(row.Cells(1).Value) < 16 Then
            row.Cells(2).Value = String.Empty
            row.Cells(3).Value = String.Empty
            row.Cells(4).Value = String.Empty
            row.Cells(5).Value = String.Empty
            row.Cells(6).Value = String.Empty
            row.Cells(7).Value = String.Empty
        End If
    Next
```

[image]